# JSON data show on first cell

Tags: ios, json

I am Developing An IOS App.On Button Click Show JSON Data In Tableview..But The Data Show ON Only First Cell Not On Other Cells..I Can Check The Data Through NSLog That Are Correct..But In Tableview Show In First Cells And Some Time App Crash And Error Data Parameters Are Nil..Warning Show on This Line

```
`"Incompatible Pointer Assigning To 'NSDictionary'
```

To

```
NSArray "[str = [BBServerJson sendPostRequest:json toUrl:url];]`
```

Any Help Or Advice Is Greatly Appreciated. Thanks In Advance.

```
    //Button Click
    BBAuthorViewController *BBAuthor =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BBAuthor"];
        BBAuthor.authorDetail=_adDetailsObj.authorDetail;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:BBAuthor animated:YES];


    //Json
     +(NSDictionary *)sendPostRequest:(NSDictionary *)params toUrl:(NSString *)urlString
{
    NSMutableString *paramString =
    [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    NSArray *keys = [params allKeys];
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
        [paramString appendFormat:@"%@=%@&",key,
         [params valueForKey:key]];
    }
    NSString *postString = @"";
    if ([paramString length] > 0)
        postString = [paramString substringToIndex:
                      [paramString length]-1];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest
                                   requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLResponse *res;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *resp = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&res error:
                    &error];


    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)res;

    int statusCode;
    statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

    NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:resp options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    return jsonArray;
}    



     NSString *url = @"https://boatbrat.com/wp-app-handler-boatsales.php";
        NSMutableDictionary *json = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [json setObject:@"AuthorListing" forKey:@"method"];
        [json setObject:_authorDetail forKey:@"author"];
        str = [BBServerJson sendPostRequest:json toUrl:url];

     //Tableview


    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return str.count;
    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
        cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        NSArray *array = [str objectForKey:@"results"];
        NSDictionary *dic= [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"author_name"];
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Row count `str.count`? Or `[str objectForKey:@"results"].count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are returning wrong row count in `numberOfRowsInSection:` method.

Change the return statement to,

```
return [[str objectForKey:@"results"] count];
```